# I am trying to insert a variable via tags into a url

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-socketio

Complete beginner here.
I am very appreciative of any support.

When I build the url from scratch and insert it(the built url) into filename using .innerHTML I get a 404 error
However when i manually copy and past the concatenated url result (from source/inspect browser page) back into my code it runs??

My HTML element I use to insert the url

```
<div id="url_string">
</div>
```

The file I am trying to insert -

```
'a_pic.jpg'
```

Approach A(hardcoding)- this runs. Not what i require though

```
<div id="url_string">
     <a  href="{{url_for('download_file', filename='a_pic.jpg')}}">
         <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px">attachment</i>
     </a>
</div>
```

Approach B (building the url) - I get an error here.
Here i receive the url from the server and pass it into javascript data.filename. From console.log, my url variable(y) is coming through.
The link paperclip file symbol comes up on the recipients page (which indicates to me that the concatinated string variable was inserted into the chat page on hearing a socket ping, as planned).

```
socket.on("sent_file", data => {
var x = "<a href=\"{{url_for(\'download_file\', filename=\'"
var y = `${data.filename}`
var z = "\')}}\"><i class=\"material-icons\" style=\"font-size:36px\">attachment</i></a>"
var entire_url_var = x + y + z
document.querySelector("#url_string").innerHTML = entire_url_var

console.log(y)
console.log(entire_url_var)
})
```

Here is the concatenated result of the above code (copied from the browser)

```
<a href="{{url_for('download_file', filename='a_pic.jpg')}}"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px">attachment</i></a>
```

From what i can tell, it is identical to the hardcoded one in approach A.
However clicking the attachment link which appears on running it, i get a 404 Error (The requested URL was not found on the server.)

What i have done so far.
I have tried many variations. Having the id in the a link not the surrounding div (and adjusting the concatenated string accordingly) amongst many others.
I suspect i am missing sth obvious.
I have spent many many hours on this and read a quite a number of other similar questions without managing to solve it just yet (other question seem syntax related, while i'm not certain whether mine is). I appreciate any support and respect your time.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are correct in that you are generating the same link in the two cases, the difference is who is interpreting the link.

In your approach A, it is Jinja2, the template engine from Flask, that handles your HTML. So you give it this:

```html
<a href="{{url_for('download_file', filename='a_pic.jpg')}}"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px">attachment</i></a>
```

And Jinja2 will notice that there is Python code in between the `{{ ... }}`. So it will execute this code and replace it with the result. So by the time this HTML snippet reaches the browser, you'll have something like this instead:

```html
<a  href="/downloads/a_pic.jpg"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px">attachment</i></a>
```

(Note that the generated href for your image might be different, you have to look at the HTML source for approach A to see exactly how does this URL looks).

In your approach B you are doing everything in the browser, so your Python server is not available. Here you have to render the URL strictly using JavaScript, you can't rely on helper functions from Flask such as `url_for()`.

So you need to generate the href in the way it looks in the browser. It would be something like this:

```js
var x = "<a href=\"/downloads/"
var y = `${data.filename}`
var z = "\"><i class=\"material-icons\" style=\"font-size:36px\">attachment</i></a>"
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing!!! Thank you so much Miguel! I understand now! That makes a lot of sense. Very appreciative.